# Programmatic access to the Java console log

Tags: java, applet, logging

Is it possible to, and if so how do you get programmatic access to the Java Console Log generated by Java applets?

What I want to do is add a "post bug" button to the applet I am developing.  When testers click this button I would like the applet to then package up the contents of the console log as part of a bug report submitted by the applet.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I doubt your exact requirement can be fulfilled, but 'sand-boxed' or 'trusted'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `System.setOut` and `setErr` you can capture output that would otherwise go to the console.

Comment: I spent ages searching for this question on here before I asked it.  Only now do I find the question and answer here too: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389632/capturing-contents-of-standard-output-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

You can append log messages to a StringBuffer object, and show in Textfield on the click of a button.

Comment: Crude (I'd go for an anonymous logger rather than a `StringBuffer`) but effective. +1