# Is there a way to get the output of another running application in Java

Tags: java

Supposing I had an application that was running permanently, and I wanted to run another application, after the first one started, to get the first one's output. Would that be possible? If possible I'd like to avoid running the first application from the second with Runtime#exec.

Comment: Unless that output is exported to a file or an external server... no

Comment: You could use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19238788/10871900)