# How to get a the output to a console as a string in java

Tags: java

I am currently trying get whatever is printed into the console and store it as a string. I must be able to hook into the System.out.println method as errors and anything created by anyone other than me must end up in the console. I have already tried using a scanner but that is only for typing into the console and I read the documentation on pipes but from my understanding you still need to give the pipe data rather than the pipe getting it from the console. Does anyone know what I need to use to get the strings printed from the console?

Comment: What code do you need? what I need is to hook into the system.out.println method

Comment: This is unclear.  Are you saying you want to intercept the output of all other programs that write to a "console"?  What if there are 10 console windows open? Do you want to capture all of them?  Why do you think the OS would allow you to read output from other programs if it was not explicitly piped to your program?

Comment: Yes i want to intercept what is being printed to my console including errors and things from library I'm using i do not need to access the console of any other programs

Comment: Well, System has a setOut() method. But I've never seen any decent library write to System.out directly. They all use a logging framework. Maybe you should just configure logging correctly. What is your use case? Why are you trying to do that?

Comment: Look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30665299/1126273 I think he didn't add any examples, but you just have to `ConsoleOutputCapturer c = new ConsoleOutputCapturer(); c.start();` and stop when you don't want to capture anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could redirect the console prints to your own stream, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5389663/1319519)!

Comment: This would have been better as a comment

Comment: Thanks this is what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I used Joacim Ericsson's resource to solve my problem. First of all i created a Output stream for my text area which was where my data was going.

```
public class ConsoleRedirection extends OutputStream{

    private JTextArea textArea;

    public ConsoleRedirection(JTextArea textArea) {
        this.textArea = textArea;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(int b) throws IOException {
        textArea.append(String.valueOf((char)b));
    }

}
```

Then i just created a print stream using my output stream and set System.out to my custom print stream.

```
    PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(new ConsoleRedirection(console));
    System.setOut(printStream);
    System.setErr(printStream);
```