# Reading the output from console and print in XML file in java

Tags: java, xml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How could I read Java Console Output into a String buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334808/how-could-i-read-java-console-output-into-a-string-buffer)

I know how to read input from user and put it on XML file.Here is the sample:
from http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-create-xml-file-in-java-dom/

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.w3c.dom.Attr;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;

public class WriteXMLFile {

    public static void main(String argv[]) {

      try {

        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

        // root elements
        Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
        Element rootElement = doc.createElement("company");
        doc.appendChild(rootElement);

        // staff elements
        Element staff = doc.createElement("Staff");
        rootElement.appendChild(staff);

        // set attribute to staff element
        Attr attr = doc.createAttribute("id");
        attr.setValue("1");
        staff.setAttributeNode(attr);

        // shorten way
        // staff.setAttribute("id", "1");

        // firstname elements
        Element firstname = doc.createElement("firstname");
        firstname.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("yong"));
        staff.appendChild(firstname);

        // lastname elements
        Element lastname = doc.createElement("lastname");
        lastname.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("mook kim"));
        staff.appendChild(lastname);

        // nickname elements
        Element nickname = doc.createElement("nickname");
        nickname.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("mkyong"));
        staff.appendChild(nickname);

        // salary elements
        Element salary = doc.createElement("salary");
        salary.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("100000"));
        staff.appendChild(salary);

        // write the content into xml file
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("C:\\file.xml"));

        // Output to console for testing
        // StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);

        transformer.transform(source, result);

        System.out.println("File saved!");

      } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
        pce.printStackTrace();
      } catch (TransformerException tfe) {
        tfe.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
}
```

but my question is how to read the output from the console in java and print it in specified XML file.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What do you mean output from the console? How are the tags identified? ...can you give a test case, i.e. with "this" output, give me "this" xml.

Comment: @Rp- that link solves my half problem i.e "How could I read Java Console Output into a String buffer" and second part is put it into a XML file.

Comment: @user1370786 Ok, now you have the data, and you know the xml structure(?), You can decide which data can go to which tag and all.. right?

Comment: @Rp- some help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly you mean by "reading the output from the console" but you can intercept calls to System.out by using http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut%28java.io.PrintStream%29.
If you elaborate more on what you are trying to do I can be more specific.

Comment: actually from console I mean the output stream.how I print it in a XML file.